# Android repeatable dialog buttons

Tags: android, dialog, imageview

I'm building a dialog that lets you click the picture multiple times, and each time you click it it changes the picture.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ViewCase.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.viewcase_largeimage);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog.setTitle(name);

            // show enlarged image
            currPic = 1;
            final ImageView imageViewLarge1 = (ImageView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewViewCasePhotoLarge1);
            imageViewLarge1.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap1);
            imageViewLarge1
                    .setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            switch (currPic) {
                            case 0:
                                imageViewLarge1
                                        .setImageBitmap(photoBitmap1);
                                currPic++;
                            case 1:
                                imageViewLarge1
                                        .setImageBitmap(photoBitmap2);
                                currPic++;
                            case 2:
                                imageViewLarge1
                                        .setImageBitmap(photoBitmap3);
                                currPic = 0;
                            }
                        }                           
                    });

            // shows the dialog
            dialog.show();
        }
```

This is my on click listener, and I can have allow for one click that changes to the second picture, but it stops after that. Any way to make the button click repeatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `switch` block you should always use `break;` after every case. Switch doesn't stop executing when it finds the right case, it goes forward and executes every case. Maybe this can be the problem, you need to try it.

Comment: Ok, so I feel dumb after that. Works perfectly now. Thanks!